# if inside a "for in" loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Checking for equality of two objects:

I am not sure about how my code flows and how can I fix this.

Inside areEqual function, I am checking "value" of two objects.

if they are equal -> isEqual=true  -> for loop shall continue 
if one of values are not equal -> isEqual = false and Break from the loop.

But i don't get the desired results. 
What logic am i exactly not understanding here?

```
    function Address (street, city, zipCode) {
    this.street = street; 
    this.city = city; 
    this.zipCode = zipCode; 
}

let address1 = new Address('a', 'b', 'c'); 
let address2 = new Address('a', 'd', 'c'); 


//checking for equality between two objects
function areEqual(address1, address2){  
    let isEqual = true; 
        for(let key in address1) {
            if(address1[key] === address2[key])
                isEqual = true; 
            else
                isEqual = false
                break; 
        }
    if(isEqual) return 'They are equal'; 
        else return 'They are not equal'; 

}

console.log(areEqual(address1, address2));
```

Comment: try to put `isEqual = false; break;` in a { } block ;)

Comment: If you have more than one statement in an if/else you need brackets. I'd argue you should just never exclude brackets to remove any ambiguity and for consistency. (Fun fact: exclusion of curly braces was the cause of apple's huge "goto fail" bug.)

Comment: thank you guys! i can see where i did wrong. newbie here

Comment: @afgphoenix No problem, everyone is a newbie at some point :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if (address1[key] === address2[key])
  isEqual = true;
else 
  isEqual = false

break;
```

You need to wrap your else condition in `{}`. Currently it breaks out of the loop on the first iteration

```js
function Address(street, city, zipCode) {
  this.street = street;
  this.city = city;
  this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

let address1 = new Address('a', 'b', 'c');
let address2 = new Address('a', 'd', 'c');

let address3 = new Address('x', 'y', 'z');
let address4 = new Address('x', 'y', 'z');

//checking for equality between two objects
function areEqual(address1, address2) {
  let isEqual = true;
  for (let key in address1) {
    if (address1[key] === address2[key])
      isEqual = true;
    else {
      isEqual = false
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isEqual) return 'They are equal';
  else return 'They are not equal';

}

console.log(areEqual(address1, address2));
console.log(areEqual(address3, address4));
```

You can avoid these type of errors if you format your code. Every code editor will have a shortcut for this functionality.

**Note**: Since you have constructor function for `Address`, this code will work. But note that, this just checks if the keys in `address1` have the same value as `address2`. If you compare an empty object like this `areEqual({}, address2)` it will log `They are equal` because it never enters the `for` loop. So, you can add an additional check if `Object.keys(address1).length` is same as that of `address2`

Answer (score 0):

You have default value of isEquls: true, so if any of keys pair will be not equals than set isEquls to false and break the loop:

```
function Address (street, city, zipCode) {
    this.street = street; 
    this.city = city; 
    this.zipCode = zipCode; 
}

let address1 = new Address('a', 'd', 'd'); 
let address2 = new Address('a', 'd', 'c'); 


//checking for equality between two objects
function areEqual(address1, address2){  
    let isEqual = true; 
        for(let key in address1) {
            if(address1[key] !== address2[key])
            {
                isEqual = false
                break; 
            }
        }
    if(isEqual) return 'They are equal'; 
        else return 'They are not equal'; 

}

console.log(areEqual(address1, address2));
```